# Как получить разницу между времененными промежутками

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Есть три временных промежутка

```
14:00
7:00
1:00
```

Надо найти разницу между ними. 14:00-7:00-1:00=**9:00**
Как мне в руби найти эту разницу?

```
t1 = Time.parse("14:00");
t2 = Time.parse("07:00");
t3 = Time.parse("1:00");
rez = t1-t2-t3
```

Логично предположить что выдаст ошибку, так как разница двух промежутков дает значение в миллисекундах

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что `Time` представляет не промежутки, а **моменты**.
Да и **у вас тоже не промежутки**, у вас **длительность**.

Да, эти три понятия различны:

- **Момент** содержит координаты (дату и время) конкретной точки на временнóй оси.
- **Промежуток** представляется двумя конкретными моментами и представляет собой время между ними.
- **Длительность** состоит только из, кхм, длительности, и не привязана к конкретным моментам вовсе.

Как бы там ни было, ваш формат длительности с лёгкостью разбирается (надёжные библиотечные средства для этого мне неизвестны, но нужны ли?):

```
hh, mm = "14:00".split(":").map(&:to_i) # => [14, 0]
```

Самым простым решением с операциями над длительностями, наверное, будет оперирование **количествами секунд**.

```
duration = hh * 3600 + mm * 60
```

(Можно и минут, но догадаться как исправить код, недолго, [а `Time#+` работает с секундами, что имеет свои удобства](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Time.html#method-i-2B).)

И всё, теперь для длительностей вам доступна обычная арифметика, только про единицы измерения при вычислениях не забывайте.

---

Но раз уж вы указали Ruby on Rails, [есть `ActiveSupport::Duration`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html).

```
# Требует только Duration, но интерфейс довольно куцый:
require "active_support/duration"
duration = ActiveSupport::Duration.build(hh * 60 * 60 + mm * 60)
#           вот он точно требует секунды ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

```
# Требует core extensions, но мало ли, может вы не любите такое
require "active_support/core_ext/integer"
duration = hh.hours + mm.minutes
```

Он реализует арифметику длительностей сам. Но как и с числами, за единицами измерения нужно следить самостоятельно, т. к. Duration не особенно парится:

```
1.month * 1.hour # => 3600 months
1.hour * 1.month # => 2629746 hours
# што
```

Со сложением и вычитанием особенных проблем быть не должно во всех случаях.