# Как прибавить часы ко времени

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Есть дата

```
t1 = "Sat, 30 Dec 1899 00:00:00 +0000"; // DateTime
```

И есть строка типа HH:MM

```
t2 = "07:05";
```

Как прибавить эти часы к t1? Чтобы получилось

```
Sat, 30 Dec 1899 07:05:00 +0000"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
require "time"

Time.parse(t1) + (Time.parse(t2) - Date.today.to_time)
```

> 1899-12-30 10:05:00 +0300

Answer (score 0):

[Я вам уже рассказывал о длительностях ранее](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/717458/181100), так вот их можно прибавлять не только друг к другу, но и к *моментам*, представленным в типе `Time`. Получатся новые моменты. Это неплохой пример того, как ООП имитирует понятия нашего мира и операции над ними.

```
require "time"
base = Time.parse("Sat, 30 Dec 1899 00:00:00 +0000")
hh, mm = "07:05".split(":").map(&:to_i)
```

Результат можно получить:

...прибавив к отправной точке **число секунд** нужной вам *длительности* ([см. `Time#+`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Time.html)):

```
base + (hh * 3600) + (mm * 60) # интуитивно это самый шустрый способ, но я не тестировал
```

...или с помощью `ActiveSupport::Duration`:

```
base + (hh.hours + mm.minutes) # скобки не особо нужны, на самом деле
```